# Linking problems in compiling a simple RSA encryption C code

Tags: c, encryption, compilation, compiler-errors

I have included the code I am using to learn RSA encryption and decryption, when I try to compile it using the command `gcc rsa.c -lcrypto -lssl` it throws linking errors.

```
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int padding = RSA_PKCS1_PADDING;

RSA * createRSA(unsigned char * key,int public)
{
    RSA *rsa= NULL;
    BIO *keybio ;
    keybio = BIO_new_mem_buf(key, -1);
    if (keybio==NULL)
    {
        printf( "Failed to create key BIO");
        return 0;
    }
    if(public)
    {
        rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY(keybio, &rsa,NULL, NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(keybio, &rsa,NULL, NULL);
    }
    if(rsa == NULL)
    {
        printf( "Failed to create RSA");
    }

    return rsa;
}

int public_encrypt(unsigned char * data,int data_len,unsigned char * key, unsigned char *encrypted)
{
    RSA * rsa = createRSA(key,1);
    int result = RSA_public_encrypt(data_len,data,encrypted,rsa,padding);
    return result;
}
int private_decrypt(unsigned char * enc_data,int data_len,unsigned char * key, unsigned char *decrypted)
{
    RSA * rsa = createRSA(key,0);
    int  result = RSA_private_decrypt(data_len,enc_data,decrypted,rsa,padding);
    return result;
}


int private_encrypt(unsigned char * data,int data_len,unsigned char * key, unsigned char *encrypted)
{
    RSA * rsa = createRSA(key,0);
    int result = RSA_private_encrypt(data_len,data,encrypted,rsa,padding);
    return result;
}
int public_decrypt(unsigned char * enc_data,int data_len,unsigned char * key, unsigned char *decrypted)
{
    RSA * rsa = createRSA(key,1);
    int  result = RSA_public_decrypt(data_len,enc_data,decrypted,rsa,padding);
    return result;
}


int main(void){

    char plainText[2048/8] = "Hello this is Ravi"; //key length : 2048

     char publicKey[]="-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n"\
    "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAy8Dbv8prpJ/0kKhlGeJY\n"\
    "ozo2t60EG8L0561g13R29LvMR5hyvGZlGJpmn65+A4xHXInJYiPuKzrKUnApeLZ+\n"\
    "vw1HocOAZtWK0z3r26uA8kQYOKX9Qt/DbCdvsF9wF8gRK0ptx9M6R13NvBxvVQAp\n"\
    "fc9jB9nTzphOgM4JiEYvlV8FLhg9yZovMYd6Wwf3aoXK891VQxTr/kQYoq1Yp+68\n"\
    "i6T4nNq7NWC+UNVjQHxNQMQMzU6lWCX8zyg3yH88OAQkUXIXKfQ+NkvYQ1cxaMoV\n"\
    "PpY72+eVthKzpMeyHkBn7ciumk5qgLTEJAfWZpe4f4eFZj/Rc8Y8Jj2IS5kVPjUy\n"\
    "wQIDAQAB\n"\
    "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n";

     char privateKey[]="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"\
    "MIIEowIBAAKCAQEAy8Dbv8prpJ/0kKhlGeJYozo2t60EG8L0561g13R29LvMR5hy\n"\
    "vGZlGJpmn65+A4xHXInJYiPuKzrKUnApeLZ+vw1HocOAZtWK0z3r26uA8kQYOKX9\n"\
    "Qt/DbCdvsF9wF8gRK0ptx9M6R13NvBxvVQApfc9jB9nTzphOgM4JiEYvlV8FLhg9\n"\
    "yZovMYd6Wwf3aoXK891VQxTr/kQYoq1Yp+68i6T4nNq7NWC+UNVjQHxNQMQMzU6l\n"\
    "WCX8zyg3yH88OAQkUXIXKfQ+NkvYQ1cxaMoVPpY72+eVthKzpMeyHkBn7ciumk5q\n"\
    "gLTEJAfWZpe4f4eFZj/Rc8Y8Jj2IS5kVPjUywQIDAQABAoIBADhg1u1Mv1hAAlX8\n"\
    "omz1Gn2f4AAW2aos2cM5UDCNw1SYmj+9SRIkaxjRsE/C4o9sw1oxrg1/z6kajV0e\n"\
    "N/t008FdlVKHXAIYWF93JMoVvIpMmT8jft6AN/y3NMpivgt2inmmEJZYNioFJKZG\n"\
    "X+/vKYvsVISZm2fw8NfnKvAQK55yu+GRWBZGOeS9K+LbYvOwcrjKhHz66m4bedKd\n"\
    "gVAix6NE5iwmjNXktSQlJMCjbtdNXg/xo1/G4kG2p/MO1HLcKfe1N5FgBiXj3Qjl\n"\
    "vgvjJZkh1as2KTgaPOBqZaP03738VnYg23ISyvfT/teArVGtxrmFP7939EvJFKpF\n"\
    "1wTxuDkCgYEA7t0DR37zt+dEJy+5vm7zSmN97VenwQJFWMiulkHGa0yU3lLasxxu\n"\
    "m0oUtndIjenIvSx6t3Y+agK2F3EPbb0AZ5wZ1p1IXs4vktgeQwSSBdqcM8LZFDvZ\n"\
    "uPboQnJoRdIkd62XnP5ekIEIBAfOp8v2wFpSfE7nNH2u4CpAXNSF9HsCgYEA2l8D\n"\
    "JrDE5m9Kkn+J4l+AdGfeBL1igPF3DnuPoV67BpgiaAgI4h25UJzXiDKKoa706S0D\n"\
    "4XB74zOLX11MaGPMIdhlG+SgeQfNoC5lE4ZWXNyESJH1SVgRGT9nBC2vtL6bxCVV\n"\
    "WBkTeC5D6c/QXcai6yw6OYyNNdp0uznKURe1xvMCgYBVYYcEjWqMuAvyferFGV+5\n"\
    "nWqr5gM+yJMFM2bEqupD/HHSLoeiMm2O8KIKvwSeRYzNohKTdZ7FwgZYxr8fGMoG\n"\
    "PxQ1VK9DxCvZL4tRpVaU5Rmknud9hg9DQG6xIbgIDR+f79sb8QjYWmcFGc1SyWOA\n"\
    "SkjlykZ2yt4xnqi3BfiD9QKBgGqLgRYXmXp1QoVIBRaWUi55nzHg1XbkWZqPXvz1\n"\
    "I3uMLv1jLjJlHk3euKqTPmC05HoApKwSHeA0/gOBmg404xyAYJTDcCidTg6hlF96\n"\
    "ZBja3xApZuxqM62F6dV4FQqzFX0WWhWp5n301N33r0qR6FumMKJzmVJ1TA8tmzEF\n"\
    "yINRAoGBAJqioYs8rK6eXzA8ywYLjqTLu/yQSLBn/4ta36K8DyCoLNlNxSuox+A5\n"\
    "w6z2vEfRVQDq4Hm4vBzjdi3QfYLNkTiTqLcvgWZ+eX44ogXtdTDO7c+GeMKWz4XX\n"\
    "uJSUVL5+CVjKLjZEJ6Qc2WZLl94xSwL71E41H4YciVnSCQxVc4Jw\n"\
    "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n";


    unsigned char  encrypted[4098]={};
    unsigned char decrypted[4098]={};

    int encrypted_length= public_encrypt(plainText,strlen(plainText),publicKey,encrypted);

    printf("Encrypted length =%d\n",encrypted_length);

    int decrypted_length = private_decrypt(encrypted,encrypted_length,privateKey, decrypted);

    printf("Decrypted Text =%s\n",decrypted);
    printf("Decrypted Length =%d\n",decrypted_length);

    encrypted_length= private_encrypt(plainText,strlen(plainText),privateKey,encrypted);

    printf("Encrypted length =%d\n",encrypted_length);

    printf("Decrypted Text =%s\n",decrypted);
    printf("Decrypted Length =%d\n",decrypted_length);

}
```

Linking errors as follows:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 3 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 4 has invalid symbol index 11
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 5 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 6 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 7 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 8 has invalid symbol index 12
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 9 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 10 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 11 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 12 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 13 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 14 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 15 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 16 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 17 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 18 has invalid symbol index 13
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 19 has invalid symbol index 21
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_line): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 2
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have ensured to use all the flags and include all the relevant header files, still I dont know why there is a linking error.

Comment: The *"undefined reference to 'main'"* seems strange. I would suggest starting with the `#include <stdio.h>` and an empty `main` function and make sure that compiles correctly. Then add all the `openssl` includes and see if that compiles.

Comment: The backslashes at the ends of the string fragments are unnecessary.  However, that observation is entirely immaterial to your linking problem.

Comment: Are you able to link simple programs normally?  Have you linked any other programs using `-lcrypto -lssl` successfully?  (The intent is to find out if the problem is peculiar to this code, somehow, or whether it is generic and this program is merely exhibiting a common problem on your system.)

Comment: yeah even the simple problems aren't compiling now :-/ something gone haywire with gcc maybe ?

Comment: Yes, something's seriously amiss with your development environment or its runtime support environment.  A reinstall of some sort is probably in order.  I'm not sure which components to sugges — it depends in part on your Linux system and the package manager it uses.  You might want to investigate what went wrong too.  Did the `crt1.o` file change recently?  If so, can you identify who did what at the time it changed?  Etc.

Comment: It compiles for me... however, I already met this *undefined reference to main* message with SDL. What happens if you replace `int main(void)` with `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` ?

Comment: I can compile the code you have provided with `gcc rsa.c -lcrypto`